# The column was specified multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I get an error with the following sql query. It says

> "The column 'Type' was specified multiple times for 'M'".

The 'M' after

```
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [ToolManagement].[dbo].[tblTools] K
    JOIN [ToolManagement].[dbo].[tblToolTypes] L ON K.ToolType = L.ToolType
)
```

is underlined in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
    SELECT          A.EntryID, A.Time, B.Name, B.Number, C.Number, D.StationNr, E.Number, E.Pressure, F.Nickname, F.Number, G.Format, G.Format, G.ID2, H.Description, I.Comment, M.Description
    FROM            [...]   A
    JOIN            [...]   B ON A.EntryID = B.EntryID
    JOIN            [...]   C ON A.EntryID = C.EntryID
    JOIN            [...]   D ON A.EntryID = D.EntryID
    JOIN            [...]   E ON A.EntryID = E.EntryID
    JOIN            [...]   F ON A.EntryID = F.EntryID
    JOIN            [...]   G ON A.EntryID = G.EntryID
    JOIN            [...]   H ON A.EntryType = H.EntryType
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [...]   I ON A.EntryID = I.EntryID
    JOIN            (SELECT * FROM [...] K JOIN [...] L ON K.Type = L.Type) M ON A.ID = M.ID
    WHERE           A.ID = '1234'
```

Comment: what happens when you change this `SELECT * FROM [...] K JOIN [...] L ON K.Type = L.Type` to `SELECT k.* FROM [...] K JOIN [...] L ON K.Type = L.Type`

Comment: It'd be probably a good idea to join `K` and `L` out of the parenthesis and then select `K.Type` or `L.Type` instead of `M.Type`

Comment: The issue here might be  this part `SELECT * FROM [...] K JOIN [...] L ON K.Type = L.Type` must be returning two same colums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that in the subquery you have aliased as `M` you are doing `SELECT *`, and the two tables involved in the join both have a `Type` column.  SQL Server is rightfully complaining that it doesn't know which `Type` column you want to select.

You only use a single type column from your subquery, and the join condition ensures that both are the same, so just select one of them:

```
SELECT
    A.EntryID, A.Time, B.Name, B.Number, C.Number, D.StationNr, E.Number,
    E.Pressure, F.Nickname, F.Number, G.Format, G.Format, G.ID2, M.Description,
    I.Comment, M.Type
FROM            [...]   A
JOIN            [...]   B ON A.EntryID = B.EntryID
JOIN            [...]   C ON A.EntryID = C.EntryID
JOIN            [...]   D ON A.EntryID = D.EntryID
JOIN            [...]   E ON A.EntryID = E.EntryID
JOIN            [...]   F ON A.EntryID = F.EntryID
JOIN            [...]   G ON A.EntryID = G.EntryID
JOIN            [...]   H ON A.EntryType = H.EntryType
LEFT OUTER JOIN [...]   I ON A.EntryID = I.EntryID
JOIN            (SELECT L.Type, L.Description FROM [...] K JOIN [...] L
                     ON K.Type = L.Type) M ON A.ID = M.ID
WHERE           A.ID = '1234'
```

Note that a select statement at the top level certainly can have two or more columns/aliases with the same name.  The problem only arises when trying to select from such a table.

Comment: i corrected a spelling mistake; I need M.Description in the first select statement

Comment: @jimmmmyjooo Answer updated.  I assumed that `L` has the description column though you can change this to `K` if I be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your inner query is selecting a `type` column from both K and L. Seeing your inner query selects every column from every table, it will thus have 2 `type` columns in the result; 1 from K, and one from L. You will need to ensure that only 1 column named `type` is returned, or that the other column is aliased to have a different name.

`SELECT * FROM [...] K JOIN [...] L ON K.Type = L.Type`

`K.Type` and `M.Type` both will be returned as `M.type`, and thus your outer query is not sure which of the two to return. If `Type` is the only column you actually need from that sub-query, just return `K.type`:

`SELECT K.Type FROM [...] K JOIN [...] L ON K.Type = L.Type`

Comment: i corrected a spelling mistake; I need M.Description in the first select statement